# C3po creates too many connections

Tags: java, oracle, c3p0, spring-jdbc

This is how my c3po Spring configuration looks like;

```
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="120" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1800" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="600" /> 
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="10" />
    <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="1" />
```

I try to monitor how many connections are made to DB so I run this script against my Oracle DB after I restart my application;

```
select
   substr(a.spid,1,9) pid,
   substr(b.sid,1,5) sid,
   substr(b.serial#,1,5) ser#,
   substr(b.machine,1,6) box,
   substr(b.username,1,10) username,

   substr(b.osuser,1,8) os_user,
   substr(b.program,1,30) program
   from v$session b, v$process a
   where
   b.paddr = a.addr and type='USER' order by spid;
```

Bu this script result shows too many connections are open, So Assuming this script results really indicates the number of sessions/connections. How can I make them less with my spring configuration? Because no matter how much I change the parameters result does not change.

Comment: For sanity you might check that ResultSet/Statement/Connection are closed. A maxPoolSize of 2 is a test I hope; less time with a larger realistic pool might be a better test.

Comment: @Joop Eggen How can I check ResultSet/Statement/Connection is closed?

Comment: Checking whether closed is mostly done by inspection of code and log. Using exception logging, spring's JdbcTemplate, try-with-resources and such helps.

Answer (score 1):

observe keenly....because maxPoolSize is for defining one pool size and a single datasource can contain multiple pools and in that case no of connections becomes

no of pools * maxPoolSize

so look for no of pools you've created

Comment: tnx where can I look for that?